# python datetime to number var?

Tags: python, datetime

how can I convert date to variable?

I tested with datetime

```
import datetime

today = date.today()
```

and idk next step.. I only need if 2020-05-01 checks player's date and gets 01(date) number to variable

Comment: try this,[strftime](https://strftime.org/) ``from datetime import datetime; datetime.today().strftime("%d")``

Comment: nice answer! thx :D
it's works too